# CSS doesn't work

Tags: php, html, css

I'm having a problem with my CSS style sheet. I try inputting the values to the DIV CLASSES, but there is no effect. The style sheet worked fine on my other HTML website, but I'm using a common header and footer via PHP on this website and it seems like it's interfering with the CSS for some reason. I don't know if my coding has any fallacies in it, but from what I can see everything looks fine:

### CSS STYLE SHEET

```
body {
    background-color: #000;
    font-family: Arial, Verdana;
    color: #fff;
}
a:link {
    color: #ff0;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
    color: #ff0;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:active {
    color: #000f;
    text-decoration: none;
}
p {
    text-align: justify;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.container {
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    width: 820px;
    height: 1350px;
    padding: 10px;
}
.header {
    background-image: url("/Images/CSS/logo.jpg");
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 20%;
    width: 100%;
}
.logo {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1),  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1),  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1),  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
    background: linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1),  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
    border: 0px solid #fff;
    height: 90%;
    width: 100%;
}
.logo h1 {
    margin: 15px;
    color: #ffa500;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    bottom: -160;
}
.logo p {
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 15px;
    color: #ffa500;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    bottom: -175;
}
.userbar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    background-color: #000;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    padding: 5px;
.body {
    border: 0px solid #fff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70%;
}
.left {
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%;
}
.right {
    border: 0px solid #fff;
    float: right;
    width: 550px;
    height: 100%;
}
.nav {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
.nav ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style-position: none;
    list-style: none;
}

.nav li {
    width: 85%;
    margin: 15px;
    color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #fff;
}
.side {
    margin-top: 25px;
    color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}
.content {
    width: 100%;
}
.content p {
    padding: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: justify;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0px;
}
.footer {
    height: 10%;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}
.footer p {
    padding: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
.pic {
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
}
.pic p {
    width: 430px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 9px;
}
.pic1 {
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}
.pic1 p {
    width: 170px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 9px;
}
.pic2 {
    float: right;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}
.pic2 p {
    width: 170px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 9px;
}
```

### Index Page

Note that the Index page itself is not html. It's a PHP file and I'm using separate PHP files for the header and footer. This is just the page source to let you see the layout of my website.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel ="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="logo">
        </div>


        <div class="userbar">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="body">
        <div class="left">
            <div class="nav">
                <ul>
                    <li>Item1</li>
                    <li>Item2</li>
                    <li>Item3</li>
                    <li>Item4</li>
                    <li>Item5</li>
                    <li>Item6</li>
                    <li>Item7</li>
                </ul>
            </div>


            <div class="side">
                <h3 align="center">News</h3>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="right">
            <div class="content">       </div><!----content----!>
    </div><!----right----!>

    <div class="footer">

    </div>
</div><!----container----!>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The very first thing to do is to validate the generated HTML: http://validator.w3.org/ and the style sheet: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/  Correct any errors and See What Happens (tm).

Comment: You have this comments at the end in your files or you just add them for this code listing?

Comment: all the comments are invalid two hyphens only no more

Comment: Where, exactly where is the style sheet (style.css) stored?  Is it in the root or is it in a root/css/ subdirectory?   Note too: you can use firefox with the firebug plug in or chrome browser (right click "inspect element") to see if content is getting loaded, how things work in CSS, etc... you could have used one of those tools to help yourself.

Comment: Oh wow! I spent 2 hours prior to posting this and couldn't figure it out, but literally five minutes after posting this question I gave myself the biggest facepalm LOL It's been resolved everyone. My bad.

Comment: The problem was in the CSS itself. I had forgotten to put a closed curly bracket it one of the values, but I got it fixed now. Thanks everyone!!

Comment: Awesome. We've all been there..Homework assignment:  Figure out how Chrome Developer tools work to troubleshoot a site.

Comment: Yeah, my bad haha I've honestly made myself the biggest idiot on this Earth, but I definitely appreciate the help. I never expected such fast responses.